# How to build Visual studio extension which install on top of an already installed extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I have built a visual studio extension tool window using VSIX package and already uploaded in the visual studio extension gallery. Now i want to build a new extension with a new extension which would add some more features to the tool window which was installed by the previous VSIX package. Is there any way for us to be able to access the tool window or the extension that are installed already in visual studio based on its GUID or something else.

I know I can release add  the new feature to old VSIX package itself with a new version no, but i wanted to make this new feature a a standalone piece so that for people who have installed the first package, this second one would install on top of that where as for them who hasn't installed the first package the second one should work on its one.

So can someone throw me some light for me on this, how do i need to check if my tool window or package is installed and if installed how do i get a reference of it so that i can change and alter it to add the new behavior.

Answer (score 0):

While you could find the toolwindow (via [IVsUIShell.FindToolWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuishell.findtoolwindow.aspx)) it is much better to replace the old package with the new one, because it's a cleaner approach. Also, if you release version 2.0 of your package, users will be notified by Visual Studio, but if you release another 1.0 package, they will miss it.